# Express.js File Upload : 60s timeouts and HTTP connection timeout errors

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multipart, node.js-connect

I'll explain very quickly what my applications does :

1. Client uploads a document
2. It gets processed
3. The server create's a snapshot image of the pdf
4. The server send's back the path to the snapshot image

Now the issue is that this whole process from step (1) through (4) takes more than 60s.

At first I had a code which used the old `express.bodyParser()`, but after 60s I would get the following error :

```
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (/DIR_TO_NODE/node/file-upload-error/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:131:17)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at abortIncoming (http.js:1911:11)
    at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (http.js:1923:5)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at TCP.close (net.js:466:12)
```

and the file in the OS's `tmp` directory was deleted.

So I decided to use the `mulster` middleware module that replaces  `express.multipart()`.

This change solved 1/2 of the problem because it removed the Express.js multipart error I would get earlier.

This means that my program keeps running now after 60s, which is good, but I still get an HTTP timeout from the client after those same 60s.

Now I know that browsers like Chrome have this fixes 60s timeout, but my question was the following :

- Is there anyway to prevent this HTTP timeout from happening after 60s ?
- If there isn't a way, how do other applications solve this problem ? I'm especially interested in cases where multiple concurrent users will have to fight for filesystem access.

Here a few test cases where I simulate a long processing by never answering the request with a `res.send()` and polling every 10s for the filenames in the `tmp` directory just to check when my file would disappear (sometimes 60s timeout, sometimes 120s timeout).

TEST CASE n°1 - with the legacy `express.bodyParser()` middleware :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');

var pid = process.pid.toString();
var interval;

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send([
        '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">' +
            '<p>Image: <input type="file" name="pdf" /></p>' +
            '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>' +
        '</form>'
    ].join(''));
});

app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

    var file_path;
    if(req.files.pdf) {
        file_path = req.files.pdf.path;
    }
    else {
        file_path = os.tmpDir() + 'test';
    }

    var filename = path.basename(file_path);
    var dir = path.dirname(file_path);

    console.log('\n> PID: ' + pid);
    console.log('> Filepath: ' + dir);
    console.log('> Filename: ' + filename);

    var count = 0;
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        console.log('\n> Interval: ' + (count * 10) + ' seconds');

        var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if(files[i].substr(0, pid.length) === pid) {
                console.log('\t-> File present: ' + files[i]);
            }
        }

    }, 10000);

});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Express started on port 3000');
```

TEST CASE n°2 - with the `mulster` middleware :

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');

var pid = process.pid.toString();
var interval;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(multer({
    dest: os.tmpDir()
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send([
        '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">' +
            '<p>Image: <input type="file" name="pdf" /></p>' +
            '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>' +
        '</form>'
    ].join(''));
});

app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

    var file_path;
    if(req.files.pdf) {
        file_path = req.files.pdf.path;
    }
    else {
        file_path = os.tmpDir() + 'test';
    }

    //var file_path = req.files.pdf.path;
    var filename = path.basename(file_path);
    var dir = path.dirname(file_path);

    console.log('\n> PID: ' + pid);
    console.log('> Filepath: ' + dir);
    console.log('> Filename: ' + filename);

    var count = 0;
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        console.log('\n> Interval: ' + (count * 10) + ' seconds');

        var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if(files[i].split('.')[0].length === 32 || files[i].substr(0, pid.length) === pid) {
                console.log('\t-> File present: ' + files[i]);
            }
        }

    }, 10000);

});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Express started on port 3000');
```

Comment: have you solved this problem? I got exactlly same error here. I've spent days on that issue, no progress yet :-(

Comment: Same here, have you found something ?

Comment: @httpete No, the only solution was to return an instant HTTP 200 after the entire file was uploaded. The processing of the file itself was done after the request was already completed. Since my application already used websockets for other reasons, processing progress %s were pushed to the client's UI using them.

Answer (score 5):

The problem looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892240/node-js-connection-reset-on-file-upload-with-multer). The 60 second timeout most likely comes from the underlying socket and can be fixed with:

```js
app.post('/', function (req, res, next) { {
    // 10 minute timeout just for POST to /
    req.socket.setTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);
    
    // ...

});
```

Comment: it works.. it is exaclty what I was looking for, just this line of code
```req.socket.setTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);```
, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see (in both cases) you have a route handler for the POST request, but in that handler you are not sending response. You should use `res.send` there too. Otherwise the user will not get response at all.

Comment: Check my update. I never send the `res.send()` on purpose to simulate a long processing time.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. You should always return response.  Otherwise the user will see nothing but a blank page.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I meant. I have an app with actual processing that takes more than 60s. But for this question I created a shorter example that would simulate my problem.