# Node.js connection reset on file upload with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer

I have a node/express app that handles file uploads with multer. Everything works well on my local machine, but on the server, if the uploaded file exceeds a couple of Mbs, the browser stops with a "connection reset" error.

Here is a simple test version of the upload script:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');

// Create server
var app = express();

// Start server
function startServer() {
    var port = 8888;
    server = app.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Node version:' + process.versions.node);
        console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env);
    });
}

var upload = multer({dest: './tmp/'});

var app = express()

app.post('/', upload.single('data'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);
});

startServer();
```

And here's the html page to test the upload:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Test Upload</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world! This is a test upload.</p>

        <form method="post" action="http://192.168.1.234:8888" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>file</label><br>
            <input type="file" name="data"><br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

I tested on two different servers – a VPS and a bare-metal box – I ended up with the same error on both servers. The upload starts and I can see a chunck of the file in my `./tmp` directory, but it never finishes and doesn't throw any error, neither in node nor in the syslog.

Comment: From my experience, it might be the timeout configuration in apache / nginx / whatever else your server(s) is running, I'd try looking into that.

Comment: Maybe not enough disk space left?

Comment: @NadavL so far node is front server, there's nothing proxying to it…

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly On one server there's several Gigs left, on the other, several hundreds, so I don't think that's the source of the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@NadavL was right, despite the fact that I had no front server, node was timing out itself.

It's written in [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback) that there's no timeout in node by default. Express might override that but I couldn't find any information on the matter.

To define a specific timeout globally, you can proceed by changing the socket timeout when the server connects

```
[…]

// Start server
function startServer() {
    var port = 8888;
    server = app.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Node version:' + process.versions.node);
        console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env);
    });

    server.on('connection', function(socket) {
        // 10 minutes timeout
        socket.setTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);
    });
}
```

But as a high timeout rises your server's exposure to [Slow HTTP Attacks](https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2011/11/02/how-to-protect-against-slow-http-attacks), you might want to change the default timeout just for a specific route – in my case, just for the upload route. In this particular case, all you have to do is change the timeout in your route's handler like so:

```
app.post('/myroute', function (req, res) {
    // 10 minutes timeout just for POST to myroute
    req.socket.setTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000);
    upload.single('data');
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

There's also a dedicated middleware to handle timeouts, it's called [connect-timeout](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout) and it can be used to configure specific timeouts for different routes too (see [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408573/need-to-reduce-the-timeout-period-for-a-route-in-expressjs)).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understood my issue, receiving ERR_CONNECTION_RESET after 60 seconds uploading big files. Increasing the request timeout with `req.setTimeout(value, cb)` isn't enough.

The server `headersTimeout` field needs to be increased manually as such:

```
server.headersTimeout = timeoutValue;
```

[Node Doc on server_headers_timeout](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_headerstimeout)

[Github issue describing the solution in details](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/35661)

Comment: I've spent to fix this issue more then 8 hours, but this answer is saved for me tens hours more. Thank you.